# Irreducible element in k[x,y] remains irreducible in k(y)[x]

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

Let $k$ be a field. Why is that an irreducible polynomial in $k[x,y]$ remains irreducible when regarded as a polynomial in $k(y)[x]$?

Comment: Have you heard of [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial))? It's basically the same as that.